# How to simulate from Nelsen 4.2.12 copula?

Tags: r, simulation, copula

I want to simulate a 3 dimensional copula from Nelsen 4.2.12 copula (copula marked as 4.2.12 in Nelsen 2006, page 116). I found an algorithm, which uses partial derivatives, in Nelsen (2006), page 41 or Bouye (2009), Page 20. For starters, I am trying to write the algorithm for 2D copula, which looks as follows:

1. Generate v1,v2 from U(0,1)
2. Set u1=v1
3. Find u2 s.t. derivative of C(u1,u2) w.r.t. u1 = v2
4. (u1,u2) is the desired pair from the 2D copula.

This algorithm can be easily extended for 3D copula. However, I am stuck at the 3rd step. The derivative of C(u1,u2) w.r.t. u1 looks very complicated and depends on u1,u2 and the copula parameter theta. Not sure how to proceed from there.

It would be great if someone knows a reference which has step by step information on this, that would be great.

Or

Another way to simulate a 3D Nelsen 4.2.12 copula.

Thanks!

Comment: Might the package `rvinecopulib` be of any help?

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the Archimedean class of copulas in this package doesn't contain Nelsen 4.2.12 copula.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to algorithm in Bouye (2009), page 20 or Nelsen (2006), page 41.

For a 3D copula with function C(.), the algorithm looks like:

1. Generate v1,v2,v3 from U(0,1)
2. Set u1=v1
3. Find u2 s.t. d/du1 C(u1,u2) = v2
4. Find u3 s.t. d/du2 d/du1 C(u1,u2) = v3
5. (u1,u2,u3) is from the desired copula.

C(.) could be complicated and hence the partial derivatives could be too, making the equations in step 3 and 4 impossible to have a closed form solution. Hence, I used numerical ways to estimate the solution. For example, if we want to solve for u2 in step 3, one can solve u2= argmin_u2 (d/du1 C(u1,u2) - v2)^2.

I hope this helps.